# turn on FIPS 140-2 with Schannel/WinSSL for just one application

Tags: windows, ssl, fips

Is it possible to turn on FIPS mode with WinSSL/Schannel only for running process instead of the whole machine (through policy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to turn on FIPS mode with WinSSL/Schannel only for running process instead of the whole machine (through policy)?

I don't know about `WinSSL` because I have never used the library. In this case, I would guess that its a YES.

For the Windows platform and `Schannel`, the answer is NO. Its either all or nothing.

The setting is controlled via `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy` (Windows XP and Server 2003) or `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled` (Vista and Server 2008). See ["System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" security setting effects in Windows XP and in later versions of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811833).